# Does the mongoimport command for a replica set require all replica set members including the arbiter?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, replicaset

I am running MongoDB 2.6.2 and I have a replica set with a primary, secondary and an arbiter. Are there any adverse effects to running a mongoimport command with only one or two of the replica set members?

More specifically, does the arbiter need to be specified in the --host option of the mongoimport command? The documentation clearly describes the hostname format ([here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--host)), but does not warn against how many of the members need to be specified.

Comment: You can specify only a single seed member. It will obtain the set configuration from that member. Its as easy as giving it a try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mongoimport` command should be run on `primary` host as this is an insert operation and all insert can be done on primary node only. `Secondary` nodes cannot entertain write operation directly. In a `replicaset`, primary node gets the data first and then `secondary` nodes reads the `primary` node's `oplog` and replicate the operations.

Simply put, if you are using a `replicaset` and you want import data using `mongoimport` then you must pass `primary` node as host to `mongoimport` command.

Also, `mongoimport` command does't care about `arbiter`. All it cares is, if it can write data to the node or not. In case of `replicaset`, you can insert data only on `primary` node.

Comment: Thank you for the response Abhay, I will mark yours as the accepted answer; however, I think that the mongoimport command should also contain the secondary members in the event that the primary instance goes down and the secondary becomes primary.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if one of the mongo instances is down for whatever reason, a mongoimport including the primary and secondary hosts will indicate a failed connection.